# Why console.log throws an error when used inside a Web Worker in firefox?

Tags: firefox, web-worker, console.log

When I use console.log to write some log to the browser from a web worker it works without issues in Chrome and IE 11 but not in Firefox. Is there any reason behind that? Or should I use a different kind of logging for web workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Firefox version with support for a `console` in workers is Firefox 29, which will be released in late April.

Unfortunately, there is still no spec for `console`, so it behaves pretty differently in different browsers in terms of where it's available and how it works.